# C: How to use decimal number in hex one to one?

Tags: c

I want to "convert" a decimal number to a hex number. **Not like `10` -> `A`.**

E.g.: `10` -> `0x10`, `55` -> `0x55`, `2021` -> `0x2021`, ...

My input is an `int`.
I already heard something about it. You can get the first digit with modulo 10. E.g. `55 % 10` is `5`. But I don't know how to get the other digits and how to put it together.

Comment: do you understand that hex numbers have base 16 where dec have base 10, for 10 -> 0x10, you have to figure out where hex number LOOKS same as dec by removing "0x", may be you have to iterate all number and convert each number to hex and then match with dec number. it looks like there is no direct formula to it.

Comment: What is the type of your input? A string like "10" when you read it from a file/input or an `int 10` itself?

Comment: I already heard something about it. You can get the first digit with modulo 10. E.g. 55 % 10 is 5. But I don't know how to get the other digits and how to put it together.

Comment: @Fractal It's an unsigned char, but you can use int as well.

Comment: The easiest way is to use a string: https://godbolt.org/z/YEEzEvns4 there's probably a faster way to do it that doesn't require strings though.

Comment: What do you mean by `convert`? The bits in memory do not change whether you represent in base 10 or 16. BTW, the `%` operator returns the remainder, not the first digit.

Comment: @babon a `55` in dec should be converted to a `55` in hex. More examples are above. `%` does indirectly if you use it with 10. `57 % 10` returns `7`.

Comment: Yes, but hex is base **16**. So you are doing no conversion, you are just sticking a `"0x"` in front of a number -- that doesn't make much sense... All numbers (in fact everything) is held in memory in binary (`1`'s and `0`'s). Whether you want to see the signed, unsigned or the hexadecimal representation -- you are just telling the computer how to display it.

Comment: @puncher Try doing this: `printf("0X%x", 55);`.

Comment: Is the "decimal number" inputted by the user? If so, convert it with `strtoul()` or similar with base 16 instead of 10.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin I don't want to display it. I have a RTC and I comminicate with that via a I2C. And this RTC has stored year, month, day, hour, minute, and second. When I want to print out the hours I have to do it like that: `printf("%x", hours)`. `hours` is `0x45` which means that 45 hours are stored in that. So basically when I have to number e.g. `12` as an dec I want to have `18` as an dec.

Comment: That makes more sense. When you query your RTC, you should be getting a time in 12 or 24 hour format. If you hour time is returned greater than `23`, then double check how you are storing/handling the value. I don't know what MCU you are working with, I do something similar with TI boards, but haven't seen hours returned greater than `23`. Would the `45` be `1` days `21` hours?

Comment: This would be why decent schools don't let students write a single line of code before they have learnt binary and hex. The theory isn't hard to grasp, it's just 1 lesson. Digit_n*base^n + Digit_n-1*base^n-1 + ... Digit_0*base^0. Everyone who wants to learn programming needs to understand this fundamental stuff before taking their first programming class.

Comment: @puncher Using `%d` inside (`printf("%d", hours)`) is not possible in your environment?

Comment: @puncher `how to get the other digits and how to put it together.` is a too broad question. The answer can also be too broad - get other digits with arithmetic operations, put it together by writing a program that does it. What have you tried? What research did you do? If you want others to write some program for you, see a freelancing site and hire a programmer. If you want to learn the language and basic arithmetic, hire a tutor or consider a good book. Surely there are resources for how to convert a number to a string - the principle in your question is the same.

Answer (score 1):

I am using this function for other purpose but I did some changes and its work fine.
you can use this :

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <string.h>
    #include <stdint.h>
    
    #define CHECK_ALPHA_HEX(REC_CHAR) (unsigned)('@' < REC_CHAR && REC_CHAR < 'G')
    #define CHECK_NUM(REC_CHAR) (unsigned)('/' < REC_CHAR && REC_CHAR < ':')
    
    void DEC_TO_HEX(int in, int *outval ) {
        
        uint8_t tbuff[5];
    
        uint8_t chr_count = 0;
    
        uint8_t len = sprintf(tbuff,"%d",in);
    
        while(chr_count < len) {
                tbuff[chr_count] -= CHECK_NUM(tbuff[chr_count]) ? '0' : CHECK_ALPHA_HEX(tbuff[chr_count]) ? '7' : tbuff[chr_count];
                *outval |= (tbuff[chr_count] << (4 *((len-1) - chr_count)));
                chr_count++;
        }
    }
    
    int main() {
        
        int out = 0;
    
        int in = 2021;
    
        DEC_TO_HEX(in,&out);`
    
        printf("%x",out);
    }
```

https://godbolt.org/z/8T9Wqb87n

Answer (score 0):

> how to get the other digits

Remove the extracted digit from input.

Repeat the extraction of one digit, until there are no more digits in input.

> how to put it together.

Learn C programming language. Write a program that implements the algorithm.

---

As I understand, an integer value has to be converted to another integer. From there it's just basic arithmetic, where the process generatally consists of:

- Getting one digit from input.
- Putting it in output.
- Removing that digit from input.
- shifting input & output to desired state

I came up with 3 separate such `convert_*` function implementations. First one is similar to common simple int->string conversion algorithms - it first converts the digits and that the results is "inverted". The second one extract the digits from propor position from input - getting the most significant base10 digit from input and moving between base10 digits of input. The third one, puts base10 digits on the end of hex number (startign from the mast significant base16 digit), and then shifts hex number to the right to handle `0x55000000` trailing zeros in result.

```
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdio.h>

const unsigned maxhexdigits = sizeof(unsigned) * CHAR_BIT / 4;

unsigned convert_andrevert(unsigned n) {
    unsigned o = 0;
    unsigned hexdigits = 0;
    // Convert hex digits from "the back"
    while (n && hexdigits != maxhexdigits) {
        o <<= 4;
        o += n % 10;
        n /= 10;
        ++hexdigits;
    }
    const unsigned swaps = hexdigits / 2;
    //printf("a %#x %d %d \n", o, hexdigits, swaps);
    // Invert hex digits
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < swaps; ++i) {
        const unsigned m1 = 0xFu << (i * 4);
        const unsigned m2 = 0xFu << ((hexdigits - i - 1) * 4);
        const unsigned road = (hexdigits - i * 2 - 1) * 4;
        // extract bits m1
        unsigned t = (o & m1) << road;
        //printf("b o=%#x i=%#x 1=%#x m2=%#x t=%#x road=%d\n", o, i, m1, m2, t, road);
        // set bit m1 in place of m2
        o = (o & ~m1) | ((o & m2) >> road);
        // set bit m2 in place of m1
        o = (o & ~m2) | t;
    }
    return o;
}

unsigned mypow10u(unsigned i) {
    unsigned r = 1;
    while (i--) {
        r *= 10;
    }
    return r;
}

unsigned convert_frommax(unsigned n) {
    n %= mypow10u(maxhexdigits);
    unsigned o = 0;
    // always start from the maximuim digit, because
    // we know it's location.
    for (int i = maxhexdigits - 1; i >= 0; --i) {
        o <<= 4;
        //printf("o=%#x u=%d pow10u(i)=%u digit=%u rest=%u\n",
                //o, i, mypow10u(i),
                //n / mypow10u(i),
                //n % mypow10u(i));
        // extract leading base10 digit
        o += n / mypow10u(i);
        n %= mypow10u(i);
    }
    return o;
}

unsigned convert_andshift(unsigned n) {
    unsigned o = 0;
    unsigned hexdigits = 0;
    // Convert hex digits from "the back"
    // put put them from the front.
    while (n && hexdigits != maxhexdigits) {
        o >>= 4;
        o += (n % 10) << (maxhexdigits * 4 - 4);
        //printf("o=%#x %d\n", o, n%10);
        n /= 10;
        ++hexdigits;
    }
    // Shift right to handle leading (trailing?) zeros.
    o >>= ((maxhexdigits - hexdigits) * 4);
    return o;
}

void testin(unsigned r, unsigned rr) {
    printf(" -> %#x %s", rr, r == rr ? "OK" : "FAIL");
}

void TEST(unsigned a, unsigned r) {
    printf("%u", a);
    testin(r, convert_andrevert(a));
    testin(r, convert_frommax(a));
    testin(r, convert_andshift(a));
    printf("\n");
}

int main() {
    TEST(1, 0x1);
    TEST(55, 0x55);
    TEST(123, 0x123);
    TEST(2021, 0x2021);
    TEST(12345678, 0x12345678);
}
```

From basic profiling, `convert_andshift` is the fastest function.

Answer (score -2):

Here is an approach:

```c
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int num = 0;
    char cNumHex[20];

    puts("Enter a decimal formed hex number: ");
    scanf("%d",&num);

    sprintf(cNumHex, "0x%d", num);

    printf("\nThe entered as hex: %s\n", cNumHex);

    return 0;
}
```

The output:

```
Enter a decimal formed hex number: 
49478

The entered as hex: 0x49478
```

Comment: Never, **ever** use `sprintf()` with user input.

Comment: @torstenvl The user input is for an example. The publisher of this question does not use a user input, it is a microcontroller project. In his/her project it is certain how many digits contains a number variable.  So let the publisher of the question decide if he/she should make use of this answer or not.

Comment: Your code invites a buffer overflow. It's an inexcusable bug.